# initcontainer issue on deployment

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am facing issue on initcontianer where i am unable to pull the value from curl and story it in variable

tried with multiple methods like passing only value
tried with passing curl method directly

NOTE: condition is when the cluster size is 3 it should come out of loop and when cluster size is not equal to 3 it should get inside loop and execute waiting for the pod

Below is the script

```bash
echo "running below scripts"
curl -g -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://hazelcast-service.bjy:8711/hazelcast/health " | jq -r '.clusterSize' > i; 
cat 'i'; 
n=`cat i`; 
while [ $n -ne 3 ]; 
do 
   echo "waiting for pod"; 
   sleep 5; 
done
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you try to do. Can you be a bit more explicit please?

Comment: condition is when the cluster size of pods  is 3 it should not enter the  loop and when cluster size is not equal to 3 it should get inside the loop and execute "waiting for the pod" message
its like ----> How to set multiple commands in one yaml file with Kubernetes?

Comment: Hi 
i am receiving the below message 4=$2: line 0: http://hazelcast-service.bjy:8711/hazelcast/health=while: not found , for below code 
          command:
            - "/bin/sh"
            - "-c"
          args : [ "http://hazelcast-service.bjy:8711/hazelcast/health=$1","4=$2","while [ curl -s $1 | sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g'  | sed s/\"//g | awk -v RS=',' -F: '$1==\"clusterSize\"{print $2}' -ne  $2 ];do sleep 5;echo 'Waiting for the webserver';done" ]